# Adjust the margin with the title on top

Tags: margins, titles

I am trying to set margin 0.5in for my latex documents. I used:

```
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
```

and it works perfectly fine. However when I added the title on top of the article, the top margin of the first page (which contains the title) does not seem to be 0.5in anymore but became bigger. Is there anyway to make it to 0.5in since I have a 3-page limit and need to put a lot of things into 3 pages.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us a short, compilable code showing how you build the title. Use package `blindtext` or simular to create dummy text ...

Answer (score 1):

You can patch `\@maketitle` to remove the inserted `2em` vertical skip using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox):

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\null\vskip 2em}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Alternatively, you can also do something crude:

```
{\def\null\vskip 2em{}\maketitle}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in,showframe]{geometry}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@maketitle}{\null\vskip 2em}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\maketitle% or...
% {\def\null\vskip 2em{}\maketitle}

\lipsum[1-17]

\end{document}
```